# Saving a random choice string to a usable variable in ansible

Tags: variables, ansible

Hoping someone can help me figure out what I feel should be a simple nested string problem. I have the following tasks to randomly choose a string, save it to a variable and print it:

```
  tasks:
    - name: Debug Section 1
      debug:
        msg: "{{ item }}"
      with_random_choice:
        - MY_CHOICE1
        - MY_CHOICE2
      register: choice

    - name: Set result to a fact
      set_fact:
        THE_CHOICE: "{{ choice.results }}"

    - name: Debug Section 3
      debug:
        msg: "{{ THE_CHOICE }}"
```

The results return with:

```
PLAY [Testing variable] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
TASK [Debug Section 1] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************ok: [localhost] => (item=MY_CHOICE1) => {
    "msg": "MY_CHOICE1"
}

TASK [Set result to a fact] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************ok: [localhost]

TASK [Debug Section 3] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "ansible_loop_var": "item", 
            "changed": false, 
            "failed": false, 
            "item": "MY_CHOICE1", 
            "msg": "MY_CHOICE1"
        }
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=3    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

I would like the variable THE_CHOICE to just return the item, but I can't seem to get it to work.  In the set_fact section I've tried the following:

```
THE_CHOICE: "{{ choice.results['item'] }}"
THE_CHOICE: "{{ choice.results.item }}"
THE_CHOICE: "{{ choice['results']['item'] }}"
```

All attempts result in something to the effect of this:

```
"The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'list object' has no attribute 'item'
```

Could anybody provide some insight into what I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be simpler to use the `random` filter (since Ansible 1.6):

```
  vars:
    choices:
      - MY_CHOICE1
      - MY_CHOICE2
  tasks:
    - name: Set fact random
      set_fact:
        THE_CHOICE: "{{ choices | random }}"
```

About your original playbook, `choice.results` is a list, containing one result for each item of the loop. In your case, it only contains one result, because the `with_random_choice` loop only iterates once. So, in order to access your item, you must select the first result of the list with `[0]`:

```
    - name: Set result to a fact
      set_fact:
        THE_CHOICE: "{{ choice.results[0].item }}"
```