# Assigning a random string from a predefined list

Tags: ansible

I need to be able to assign to a variable a random string out of two or more strings. In this case, either `server1` or `server2` on a random basis.

I looked at the implementation here [Saving a random choice string to a usable variable in ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61533369/saving-a-random-choice-string-to-a-usable-variable-in-ansible)

Here is my variable file:

```yaml
vars:
  server_options:
    - 'server1'
    - 'server2'

tasks:
  - name: Set Lab host
    set_fact:
      allocated_server: "{{ server_options | random }}"
```

I also tried a second approach:

```yaml
- name: Pick a random host
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item }}"
  with_random_choice:
    - server1
    - server2
  register: my_host
  
  
- name: Assign host to a variable
  set_fact:
    allocated_server: "{{ my_host.results[0].item }}"
```

Comment: The second approach is odd, because you should not use `debug` to assign variable, you should use `set_fact`, rather. But what does not please you une the first one?

Comment: Mind that your indentation are buggy, you should indent the variable one level deeper in a `set_fact`.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε with the first approach, I get the error from ansible tower `{"msg" "'allocated_server' is undefined"}`

Comment: [I cannot reproduce](https://gist.github.com/b-enoit-be/563aecb8d8920c72cab2798958453f73)

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε Thanks for this, so where it is being used its a vars file and not a play. I am thinking of moving the code into the next play, how can the random functionality be used within a vars file and other plays can access the variable value ?

Comment: A variable file is what it is: a variable file. If you want to define a variable, you should make it a variable, not a `set_fact`, which is a **task**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue seems to be coming from the fact that you are confusing `vars_files` that should only contain variables, with an import of task, somehow.

In a variable file, nothing prevents you to use a Jinja filter though, so, what you are looking for is definitely easily achievable.

Given the file *vars.yml*:

```yaml
server_options:
  - server1
  - server2

allocated_server: "{{ server_options | random }}"
```

And the playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no

  vars_files:
    - vars.yml

  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: allocated_server
```

This yields:

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => 
  allocated_server: server1
```

Or

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => 
  allocated_server: server2
```